# Building Unreal Engine 4 on OS X - Xcode 5.1 error

Tags: xcode, macos, mono, unreal-development-kit, unreal-engine4

I have been trying to build UE4 on mac for the past hour or so.
I have the project files generated, opened in Xcode, selected to build UE4Editor but after a while I get the following errors.

```
ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/UnrealEngine4/Engine/Binaries/Mac/UnrealHeaderTool
Cumulative action seconds (4 processors): 0.00 building projects, 256.19 compiling, 0.00 creating app bundles, 0.00 generating debug info, 0.00 linking, 0.00 other
UBT execution time: 132.94 seconds
ERROR: UnrealHeaderTool failed for target 'UE4Editor' (platform: Mac, module info: /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/UnrealEngine4/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Mac/UE4Editor/Debug/UnrealHeaderTool.manifest).
Showing first 200 notices only
```

but this one is remarked with a red exclamation symbol:

```
Command /Users/XXXXXX/Desktop/UnrealEngine4/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Mac/Build.sh failed with exit code 1
```

I had a problem building the project files because everything in /Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Mac and /Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/bin had DOS line ends.
I executed Dos2unix * and chmod a+x * on both folders and i was able to generate the project files just fine.
I don't know why that would happen, but I believe the source code went through a windows machine but i don't know if that was the cause of that issue or if it is what other issue would cause me.

any help help debugging this error would be very appreciated.

I just noticed, I seem to have this error dumped all over the log too:

clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg:

---

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/92/2cw5q21565v95tql9qcm_br00000gn/T/Module-e4221e.mm
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/92/2cw5q21565v95tql9qcm_br00000gn/T/Module-e4221e.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg:

seems to happen after this comes up:

Building UE4Editor...
Compiling with Mac SDK 10.8
Building UnrealHeaderTool...
Compiling with Mac SDK 10.8
xcrun Module.CoreUObject.1_of_5.cpp
xcrun Module.CoreUObject.4_of_5.cpp
Stack dump:

so clang is failing to compile UnrealHeaderTool?

Comment: Are you using os x 10.9.2? And did you install the additional required updates from github as well?

Comment: wow thanks for the response. (didnt get a notification..)
I think at the time I was using 10.9.3, i did install the required updates.
I solved the issue. I had to set correct permissions in all of the folders and subfolders and also there was alot of scripts with DOS line endings. namely in:
/UnrealEngine/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/Mono/Mac/bin
/UnrealEngine/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Mac
I also had to compile with xcode 5.1 but use the command line utilities of 5.0.2.
Ive successfully built all subsequent UE4 releases since then.
Mostly I think this was a permissions error.